# How to make this SQL query to use index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have this table named `orders` which has this index

`"orders_market_id_owner_id_status_idx" btree (owner_id, market_id, status)`

Also, I have a table named `users` which contains the `role_alias` attribute, which has these possible values `(bot, member)`.

I am trying to get the records from `orders` that are not created by `bot` users, here are the queries which I have tried and not using the index:

```sql
-- 2 & 3 are the user_id of bots which I want to filter out
EXPLAIN 
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN users as u ON o.owner_id = u.id 
WHERE owner_id NOT IN (2,3) AND o.market_id = 'btcusdt' LIMIT 10;

EXPLAIN
SELECT o.* 
FROM orders AS o 
WHERE o.owner_id IN (
  SELECT id FROM users AS u WHERE u.role_alias != 'bot') 
  AND o.market_id = 'btcusdt';

EXPLAIN
SELECT o.* 
FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON u.id = o.owner_id 
WHERE u.role_alias != 'bot' AND o.market_id = 'btcusdt';
```

The possible reasons why this query is not using the index are:

- Using not equality operator `u.role_alias != 'bot'`
- Using the `IN` operator `IN (SELECT id FROM users AS u WHERE u.role_alias != 'bot')`

Can someone kindly suggest how to get the orders by filtering out the rows and using index?

Comment: Must it be this index? All queries shown want exactly one market_id, so the most appropriate index would have this as the first column. An index on (market_id, owner_id) would seem perfect.

Comment: You need to add the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the queries  to your question.

Comment: In the first query, why are you joining `users`? It's not used at all.

Comment: Something to be aware of, by the way: Sometimes, not using any index is the fastest way to select the data.

Comment: On a side note: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is seldom desired. Usually we want the "best" rows, not some rows the DBMS happens to stumble upon first.

Comment: @TheImpaler I am using join to get the user email as well. Which I have removed now for the sack of simplicity.